# Permalink, links a page to the homepage

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, custom-post-type

So I'm using the 'post-name' pretty permalink structure.

I have a page called The Trust, the slug of this page is the-trust.

But when i go onto www.mydomain.com/the-trust, it shows the the homepage. The URL stays the same, but it displays the index.php page.

It used to show me the archive.php page, but I removed that from my theme files so now it shows me the index page.

How can I fix this?

If i change the slug to the-trusts, it displays the page fine, however I want the slug to stay as the-trust.

I used to have a php file in my theme folder called thetrust.php (i've removed that now), the template file that is assigned to The Trust page is called trust-articles.php

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The page does work with Ugly permalinks so www.domain.com/?page_id=174

EDIT .htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

EDIT FIX:
The problem was that I didnt have an archive page for The Trust posts, so it was leading to default archive page, and when I deleted that it redirected to homepage. So to fix it I just created a custom-archive page. Now it works.

Comment: Can you try changing the permalink structure and then revert it back?  This often solves some odd permalink behaviour, and ensures your `.htaccess` is correct.

Comment: Hi Mike, I have tried resetting the permalinks but there was no change to the error. My htaccess file should be correct, as it was created by WP.

Comment: Do you know if you are on an Apache or IIS based server? If you are on IIS, you will need a web.config file

Comment: Hey Swiss, im pretty sure the servers are Apache based

Comment: [Read this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)  

`If you've tried to navigate to a newly created Page and encounter an error, you likely need to update your Permalink structure. Remember, each time you add a new static Page to WordPress, new rules must be generated and updated to .htaccess (WordPress 1.X) or to the internal rewrites array (WordPress 2.X).`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. The problem was that I didnt have an archive page for The Trust posts, so it was leading to default archive page, and when I deleted that it redirecred to homepage. So to fix it I just created a custom-archive page. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure....

1. You never delete any core file from wordpress theme.
2. page slug does not override any other category or post or post type slug.
3. Check **Setting > Reading** if "**The Trust**" page is set to home page there.
4. If "The Trust" is a page then add its page named as "*page-the-trust.php*". You dont have to add any other page and make it a template.

These may fix your problem. If not i'm sure thing is pretty messed up.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. The problem was that I didnt have an archive page for The Trust posts, so it was leading to default archive page, and when I deleted that it redirecred to homepage. So to fix it I just created a custom-archive page. Now it works.

Comment: You never mentioned it as a "custom post type", rather you mentioned it as "page". That's why i told you to create page-the-trust.php. For custom post type default archive page is mandatory. For custom template you need to create archive-the-trust.php.